# Add month to array to account for 0 indexing?

Tags: javascript, pickadate

I am using pickadate.js (https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) and it seems that the function of disabled date is off by 1 month, for example if you go to the example page, it gives the example of `[2015,3,3], [2015,3,12],[2015,3,20]` being disabled, however if you open the date picker it shows that April (the 4th month of the year) 3, 12, and 20th are disabled, not March (the 3rd month of the year).

Either I am doing something very wrong or this is a pretty big bug. I have already left a comment on Github about this issue, but assuming it is a bug, is there a way I can build an array to correct for this error?

Example of what I want to do:

```
    var fixeddates = [
      [2019,8,19]
      [2019,10,11]
      [2019,10,12]
    ];
fixeddates.setMonth(fixeddates.getMonth() - 1);

$('.datepicker').pickadate({
  disable: [
    [fixeddates]
  ]
})
```

If someone could correct the code to properly work in an array, that would be awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From their website:
[image: From their website]

Reference: https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/

Comment: Gotcha, could you help me with a work around to this problem?

Comment: If you have dates that must be in the format you have in `fixeddates`, just write a helper method to reduce all the month integers by 1 before you pass them to `pickadate`